# TFS Release Management Rejected

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

The release is created via TFS 2015. We just add 2 simple environments as following and link the release with a build.
[image]
But when the release is triggered, it always fail and the log shows "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

[image]

Is there any thing wrong with my setup? The release and build are using the same queue. And the agents attached onto the queue are work because the build (vNext Build) can success. Anyone can help on this problem??

Update:
And the log only shows "Deployment on this environment was cancelled". What is the root cause of that?
[image]

Comment: The screen shot of log was updated. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The TFS version is: Version 14.95.25229.0

Comment: That's TFS 2015 Update 2.1

Comment: Looks like there is an existing Connect issue on this topic as well: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2745800/release-fail-with-deployment-on-this-environment-was-cancelled-message

Comment: The problem is we are using the vNext build instead of XAML build.

Comment: Can you check whether your project has a "Project build service" user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113497/discussion-between-max-and-jessehouwing).

Comment: Is there any log generated in your agent "_diag" folder?

Answer (score -1):

Please check the call stack in the  event viewer as mentioned at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2745800/release-fail-with-deployment-on-this-environment-was-cancelled-message and if it is same call stack then you hit the same bug which will be fixed with TFS2015U3. For now to unblock yourself, you may write to RM_Customer_Queries@microsoft.com and i shall help you getting a dll with the fix which you can patch on your setup.

As the dll would be not officially signed by microsoft hence you have to wait for TFS2015U3 to be released to be used in any production environment. You can try it in a test environment though.

Comment: 1. I cannot found any event log related with my build agents on the machine where the agents running.
2. Yes, we have the project build service user in our project, but if I remove these (we have 2 of them with the same identifier) user, our build cannot run, and it complain: 
##[error]TF14044: Access Denied: User Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION) needs the AdminWorkspaces global permission(s).

Comment: Can you please check the event viewer of server machine? start command prompt --> eventvwr --> Applications and Services Logs --> Microsoft Team Foundation Server --> Debug ( do repro and check error log).